# Добавить загрузку нативной библиотеки

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

У меня есть Android приложение и там имеются нативные библиотеки на С++. Как мне добавить свою библиотеку на С++ и загрузить ее не имея исходного кода?

Comment: Загрузить куда? И в каком виде она у Вас?

Comment: Нативная библиотека Android NDK на С++ (.so). Хочу ее загрузить к другим которые уже имеются в Android приложении, но исходного кода приложения я не имею поэтому я не могу добавить загрузку уже своей библиотеки.

Comment: Это похоже на проблему XY. Лучше опишите, чего вы на самом деле пытаетесь добиться загружая какую-то левую библиотеку в стороннее приложение.

Comment: Моддинг интерфейса приложения. Я пытался декомпилировать classes.dex и добавить загрузку своей библиотеки, скомпилировал обратно, с помощью APK Tools скомпилировал обратно приложение, но библиотека не загружается просто. Предварительно закинув свою библиотеку в lib/armeabi...

Comment: Я подключал, но у меня было название класса и список статических функций к которым обращался, у вас есть такое?